# why use MH for Gaussian prior when its the conjugate prior

Tags: normal-distribution, metropolis-hastings, conjugate-prior

As I understand, gaussian likelihood function has a conjugate prior for μ which is also a gaussian. In that case, the posterior can be derived in closed form. Why do some many papers use metropolis hastings to find the posterior?

Comment: Can you provide references to those papers? Are they computing *only* the simple normal-normal model, or something more complicated?

Comment: In all likelihood, those papers (and books) use the Gaussian example as an illustration since the true posterior is known in closed form and can be compared to the Metropolis-Hastings output. For instance, in our [book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441915753?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441915753), Example 7.3 runs a MH algorithm on the normal model.

Comment: I think I got it. The author meant to go Gibbs sampler on both μ and σ2. That's why the MCMC. Thanks for the reponse.